# codeigniter view loading css content

Tags: html, css, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and it may sound stupid but I can't figure it out.

I wanted to load an HTML template and I copied the whole content in views directory, but when I loaded the page in the controller, the page doesn't have any CSS, JavaScript or images.

Its just plain, as you can see below, it's just text without content.

[image]

I even tried adding the CSS, JS and image folders in the main codeigniter route next to `index.php`, but it didn't work either.

```
<?php
class Test1 extends CI_Controller{
    function index(){
        $this->load->view('index.html');
        function _test2()
        {


        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: You should read their documentation carefully. They have a pretty good one. Follow this link https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html , hope it will help you.

Comment: What is in the view? specifically between `<header>` and `</header>`

Comment: its an ordinary html file just like the others nothing special about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen because of the url which you are passing.

Your URL : `localhost/igniter/index.php/test`
and your file is located in `igniter/index.html`, So u have to folow the below steps.

**Method 1**

Step 1:  remove index.php from your url. For this use the following code

`RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

Step 2: You have to reset the links in your html page as `../*followed by your file name*` You have to include `../` on every links in html page

Now enter your url as `localhost/igniter/test`. It will display all the image with css designs.

**Method 2**

You can use IFrame to view the page with same design.

If you need more assistance on this, I'm happy to guide you through.